# Remove VCR/Webmock logs from stdout when running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, vcr, webmock

On a standard Rails 3.2.19 project, when running tests with RSpec I'm getting these logs on stdout when using VCR cassettes:

```
Request[post]: https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay                                                            |  ETA: ??:??:?? 
Response[200]: OK, Duration: 0.004s
```

How can I make these go to log/test.log instead?

Answer (score 0):

Check your ***spec_helper.rb*** and remove the line, if any:

```
c.debug_logger = $stderr
```

You can use a file for those logs, [source](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/vcr/vcr/VCR%2FConfiguration%3Adebug_logger).